# why is my code giving 'int' object is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python

```
t= int(input())
ar=[]
chk=0
x=0
y=0
while(t>0)
    i=int(input())
    for l in range(i):
        ar= int(input())
    for l in range(i-1):
        for m in range(l+1,i):
            x=ar[l]
            y=ar[m]
            k=x*y
            if k in ar:
                continue
            else:
                chk=chk+1
    print(True)
    if chk>0:
        print(False)
    t-=1
```

Error:

```
x=ar[l]
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

in this program i am tryng to print true if all the all the pairs in the array follow the relation x= a*b where x is any element in array and a abd b are the elements of the pair.

Comment: `ar` is an integer: `ar = int(input())`. You can't subscript an integer.

Comment: In the loop above, put `ar[l] = int(input())` instead of `ar= int(input())`

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ar` wrong. First you use `ar` like a list, and then like an int.

```
ar=[]               # You are using ar like a list
ar= int(input())    # Now, you are using ar like an int
```

You have to append the value:

```
ar.append(int(input()))
```

Now you are making a good list!

Answer (score 1):

What you intend to do is append the input to the `ar`. Use

```
ar.append(int(input())
```

instead of

```
ar = int(input())
```

which changes `ar` type from `list` to `int`, and it's no longer possible to access it using indices.